# Smarty input field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, templates, smarty

I want to add some value in an input field with jQuery in my Smarty tpl file. If the hostname input field is left blank and you hit the order button it should add an general domain name to the input field. Like w1.test.local. But its not working

**Smarty tpl file:**

```
<div>
<input class="hostname-box" type="text" name="domain" required="" value="">
<a href="#host" class="button">Add</a>
</div>

<div>
<a href="#submit" class="button">Order</a>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$('.button').click(function(){
    var fieldID = $(this).prev().attr("hostname-box");
    fieldID = fieldID.replace(/([\[\]]+)/g, "\\$1");
    $('#' + fieldID).val("hello.domain.local");
});
```

**But getting this error :**

> VM3715:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of
>   undefined
>       at HTMLAnchorElement. (:3:23)
>       at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery.js:3)
>       at HTMLAnchorElement.r.handle (jquery.js:3)

Comment: The preceding element of `.button` doesn't have an attribute called `hostname-box`

Comment: @ElAoutarHamza Okay what should i do ? Can you help me with an example ?

Comment: I honestly don't understand  what you are trying to do in your code, could you explain more ?

Comment: @ElAoutarHamza I have an input field which is required. But you can not leave it blank. So if someone keeps it blanks it should adds test.vps.local as hostname if someone press the order button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the input class as a selector to change it's value :

```
$('.button').click(function(){
    var jHostName = $('.hostname-box');
    var hostNameValue = jHostName.text().trim();

    if(hostNameValue === '') {
        jHostName.val("hello.domain.local");
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f7339030/)

I personally would use other class than `button`, since it's too generic.

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic ?

Comment: the jQuery is also putting "hello.domain.local" if i try to add an own value into the input field. It should only be putting "hello.domain.local" if its empty